# Kafka exception leader not available

Tags: exception, apache-kafka

I install Kafka
And start zookeeper and Kafka server it works fine
But after I hit send button in postman it shows 500 internal server error.
In console it shows correlation I'd 13: {demo =Leader not available}

And partition demo to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to (random number)

I want the reason why it gives error